# How to check if vim window has admin rights and how to add it to the statusline?

Tags: vim, admin, status

I noted that:
Vim with admin rights can only open files from program with admin rights.
Vim without admin rights can only open files from programs without admin rights.

This makes it that I often have two windows of more of vim open with different rights.
I often don't know if the one I use has admin rights or not.

Is it possible to check if a vim window has admin rights or not?

I would like to add the admin status to the statusline, something like this:

```
function! CheckAdminMode()
  if &admin | return 'Admin' | else | return '' | endif
endfunction

set statusline+=%*\ %{&admin}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a shell command you can use `system()`. E.g. for most home linux setups

```
if system('echo $EUID') == 0 " Implicit type cast, string->int for left operand
    return 'Root'
else
    return ''
endif
```

(`$EUID` is normally a shell special variable not present in exported environment thus using `if $EUID == 0` is not possible) or, faster,

```
py import os
return (pyeval('os.geteuid()') == 0) ? 'Root' : ''
```

. As you are asking for admin and not root I assume you are not on linux, thus I can’t help you with the command to check. You can always use indirect check: test whether you have right to write to some directory writeable only for administrators:

```
" filewritable() reports 2 for writable directories which is also true
return filewritable('C:\Windows\System32') ? 'Admin' : ''
```

.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I,m on windows but have python and cygwin installed.

Comment: @Remonn It is irrelevant. I do not use windows and cygwin and know about the latter much less then about the former.

Comment: Does `if system('echo $EUID') == 0` work in your vim? I was never enable to let it work. It returns an system admin window what never stops flickering. Now I have python installed on my PC and today I tried your python code, but that gives this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geteuid'`

Comment: Ah... this works fine in windows :) `return filewritable('C:\Windows\System32') ? 'Admin' : ''` Tnx again.